# UPDATE Table with AJAX PHP not initializing

Tags: php, ajax, sql-update

im calling my AJAX functioin like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < remove.length; i++) {

    remove[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        removeName = $(this).attr("id");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: {deleteName: removeName}
        });
    });

}
```

In my ajax.php i have a function like this:

```
  if (filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'deleteName') != "") {
    $messageManager->deleteMessages(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'deleteName'));
}
```

My `deleteMessages()` function looks like this:

```
public function deleteMessages($deleteName) {
    $sql = 'UPDATE ' . self::TABLE . ' SET rdelete=? WHERE receiver = ? AND sender=? OR sdelete=? WHERE receiver=? AND sender=?';
    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(1, $_SESSION['user']->getName(), $deleteName, 1, $deleteName, $_SESSION['user']->getName()));
}
```

I have tried to use `file_put_contents()` in the `deleteMessages()` function to check if it gets accessed, but there is no file being created.

The variable that AJAX is sending, is indeed filled with the desired string.
But some how in the ajax.php the POST is not being recognized... but only for "deleteName", everything else works fine.

Is my syntax wrong? im lost!

Actually i want to set rdelete=1 where receiver=me and sender=friend and set sdelete=1 where receiver=friend and sender=me

Comment: I think, wrong syntax near ajax code. Use this.. $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "ajax.php",
     data: {deleteName: removeName},
 cache:false,success:function(result){
 alert(result);
}});

Comment: I would var_dump($_POST['deleteName']) and compare it to var_dump(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'deleteName')) in ajax.php

Comment: Just a side note: might consider assigning the `filter_input()` to a variable inside your `if` statement. Like: `if ($id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'deleteName'))`

Comment: thanks my ajax works now :D

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is wrong. You have **TWO** `where` clauses, which is illegal.

```
WHERE receiver = ? AND sender=? OR sdelete=? WHERE receiver=? AND sender=?
^^^^--- clause #1                            ^^^^^---clause #2
```

It should be something more like:

```
WHERE ((receiver = ?) AND (sender = ?)) OR (sdelete =1) OR  ((receiver =? AND (sender = ?))
```

Note the extra `()` sets. You've got `and` and `or` clauses in there, which means you'll have to use `()` to enforce the logic evaluation order. The above is my best guess as to what you're trying to accomplish, but probably isn't what you really want.

And if you had even bare bones error handling on your DB calls, you'd have been informed about the syntax errors. By default, MySQLi and PDO simply default to silent failure, and returning boolean false. Never EVER assume success. Always assume failure, check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: I tried your code but its not working. Ill test the ajax too

Comment: actually i want to set rdelete=1 where receiver=me and sender=friend and set sdelete=1 where receiver=friend and sender=me

Comment: well, whatever it should be, you need to fix the sql.